# Dynamic images, preventing cache from the page that generates image

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have one page that generates png images on the fly,project is not over yet so I didn't test it but I can assume that I will have problem with images chaching.

The images my page generates will be used mostly on forums, as signature. Since no code is allowed except some BBCode(images,links) Im not sure is it even possible disable caching from my page that generates image?

I can already imagine situation: User puts img tags in his forum signature leading to my page that generates dynamic images for his signature. When he first opens page, his browser caches image, and each time he opens that page even if I stream different image, he will see the old one?

Will that really happen, or did I assume wrong? If this does happen, is there any way around it?

Comment: are u want to prevent caching on a Page ?

Comment: I am just asking if it is possible to prevent caching from my page that genrates Image as stream since I don't have access to the page that it will be posted on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the Cache-Control "no-cache" header

```
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
```

Comment: So this works if image gets called from different page outside of my doimain, if I understood it correctly: my Image would send it's own header in response?

Comment: This would add the no-cache header to the image response stream